# Comparing time, hh:mm and h:mm in PHP

Tags: php, regex, time

I am having a problem with comparing `hh:mm` and `h:mm`, example code below. Please note that this is an example, in actual fact, I am retrieving data from the database.

This code checks for `hh:mm` and `h:mm` time format using `pregex` and also checks if `$EndTime` is earlier than `$StartTime` it will `echo 'Time Error'`, basically `EndTime` cannot be earlier than `StartTime` (EndTime should be later than StartTime). So if either one of the checks is true, it will `echo 'Time Error'`.

```
$StartTime = '8:00';
$EndTime = '19:00';
if(!preg_match("/^(?:2[0-3]|[01][0-9]|[0-9]):[0-5][0-9]$/", $StartTime) || ($StartTime > $EndTime)){
    echo 'Time Error';
}
else{
    echo 'Time Correct';
}
```

The above code will `echo 'Time Error'` is if I use `8:00` as my `StartTime`. However, if I use `08:00` as my `StartTime` it will `echo 'Time Correct'`.

if I change it to:

```
$StartTime = '19:00';
$EndTime = '8:00';
```

It will `echo 'Time Correct'`, which should not be the case as `EndTime` is earlier than `StartTime`. Same thing, if I change it to `08:00` it show me the correct message.

Checked `pregex` for `8:00` and `08:00` and both are correct time format.

Why is it so and how do I fix this error? Is there something wrong with the comparing of time?

Thanks in advance for any help rendered.

Thank you Lucas Arbex for the strtotime suggestion. It seems to work now.

```
$startTime = ('00:00');
$endTime = ('08:00');

if((!preg_match("/^(?:2[0-3]|[01][0-9]|[0-9]):[0-5][0-9]$/", $startTime)) || (strtotime($startTime) > strtotime($endTime)) || (!preg_match("/^(?:2[0-3]|[01][0-9]|[0-9]):[0-5][0-9]$/", $EndTime))){
  echo 'Time Error';
}
else{
  echo 'Time Correct';
}
```

Comment: Just add a leading `0` if either time starts with a single digit, then compare them as strings.

Comment: Or use `strtotime()` to parse the times.

Comment: to be clear, the problem is those are strings, and comparing strings is like sorting words, so it will sort on the first character. 1 comes before 8, so '19:00' is before '8:00'

Comment: Because I'm retrieving time from excel and into a database, I am checking every time value, do I need to add 0 to all time with a single digit in front every time?

Comment: @Barmar will that affect my preg match checking? How should I go about implementing it?

Comment: First do the format validation. if both times are correct format, add the 0's.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `strtotime()` to parse the string into datetime after the validation, like so:

```
$starttime = '19:00';
$endtime = '8:00';

$validatedStarttime = preg_match("/([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9](:[0-5][0-9])?/", $starttime);
$validatedEndtime = preg_match("/([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9](:[0-5][0-9])?/", $endtime);

if($validatedStarttime && $validatedEndtime) {
    if(strtotime($starttime) > strtotime($endtime)) {
        echo 'Time Error';
    } else {
        echo 'Time Correct';
    }
} else {
    echo 'Incorrect Format';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the format checking separate from the time comparison. Add a leading zero if the time doesn't already have one.

```
if(!preg_match("/^(?:2[0-3]|[01][0-9]|[0-9]):[0-5][0-9]$/", $StartTime) || !preg_match("/^(?:2[0-3]|[01][0-9]|[0-9]):[0-5][0-9]$/", $EndTime)){
    echo 'Time Error';
} else {
    if ($StartTime[1] == ":") {
        $StartTime = "0" . $StartTime;
    }
    if ($EndTime[1] == ":") {
        $EndTime = "0" . $EndTime;
    }
    if ($StartTime > $EndTime) {
        echo 'Time Error';
    } else {
        echo 'Time Correct';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can validate the incoming time expressions and check for the optional leading zero within the regex pattern.  There is no need to make the extra `strtotime()` calls.

Code: ([PHP Demo](https://3v4l.org/f3a8gu)) ([Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bQsv1N/2))

```
$startTime = '19:00';
$endTime = '8:00';

if (!preg_match("~^(?|(2)\K[0-3]|([01]?)\K\d):[0-5]\d$~", $startTime, $start) || 
    !preg_match("~^(?|(2)\K[0-3]|([01]?)\K\d):[0-5]\d$~", $endTime, $end) ||
    (int)$start[1] . $start[0] > (int)$end[1] . $end[0]
) {
        // var_export($start);
    echo "\nTime Error\n";
        // var_export(((int)$start[1] . $start[0]) . ' versus ' . ((int)$end[1] . $end[0]));
}
// outputs: Time Error
```

The above technique uses a pattern that captures the hour digit (optional if trailed immediately by another digit), then restarts the fulstring match with `\K`.  A "branch reset" `(|...|...)` is used to make sure that both capture groups are treated as element `[1]` in the match array.  By making the leading digit optional, you can omit the third branch in your original pattern.  Also, I prefer the shorter `\d` over `[0-9]`.

---

If this is too messy|complicated for you, you could also consider allowing php to compare the two strings as float values.

Code: ([PHP Demo](https://3v4l.org/BhVdH))

```
if (!preg_match("~^(?:2[0-3]|[01]?\d):[0-5]\d$~", $startTime) || 
    !preg_match("~^(?:2[0-3]|[01]?\d):[0-5]\d$~", $endTime) ||
    str_replace(':', '.', $startTime) > str_replace(':', '.', $endTime)
) {
    echo "\nTime Error\n";
        // var_export(str_replace(':', '.', $startTime) . ' versus ' . str_replace(':', '.', $endTime));
}
```

---

And of course, you can unconditionally apply left-side padding with zeros. (As you can see, there are many ways to skin this cat.)

```
if (!preg_match("~^(?:2[0-3]|[01]?\d):[0-5]\d$~", $startTime) || 
    !preg_match("~^(?:2[0-3]|[01]?\d):[0-5]\d$~", $endTime) ||
    str_pad($startTime, 5, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT) > str_pad($endTime, 5, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT)
) {
    echo "\nTime Error\n";
        // var_export(str_replace(':', '.', $startTime) . ' versus ' . str_replace(':', '.', $endTime));
}
```